# Getting a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to install a project with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, xtext

Trying to build an eclipse plugin. When I try to run mvn install I get this error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/xtext/common/types/DefaultCommonTypesRuntimeModule
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
```

Apparently a NoClassDefFoundError means that the class isn't available at runtime. This plugin doesn't actually run xtext code but it is built using an xtext language plugin. My guess would be that there would be a problem with getting that code at runtime? I maven installed the parent plugin and even linked it's jar locally through maven and this still pops up. Ideas?

Also heres the project's pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis</groupId>
    <artifactId>archnemesis-pmd-rule</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Archnemesis PMD Plugin</name>
    <description>Archnemesis rule implementation for PMD</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis-core-rule</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtend.lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please check if your `.m2` directory contains the jar or not and try to run mvn with `-U` command  `mvn install -U`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.common.types</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```